# CHAT: CREATE: invalid/missing user handle(s) as argument

Tags: java, skype

I am trying to send skype message through skype-java-api-1.5 but it is throwing this exception on the line where actual send method is invoked. Here's my code piece:-

```
    try {
    for(Chat c : Skype.getAllChats()) {
        if(c.getId().contains("part of id"))
                Skype.chat(c.getId()).send("Hi!");
    }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```